# Multiple definition of main without any .cpp file in project folder c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a project which only contains one .cpp file. I'm pretty sure that there is no other files within the folder, but eclipse keep giving me:

```
multiple definition of `main'
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string input;
    vector<double> value;
    int count = 0;

    while(input != "#") {

        cout << "Enter value " << count + 1 << "\n";
        cin >> input;
        if (input != "#") {
            value[count] = atof(input.c_str());
        }
        count++;
    }

    cout << count;
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        sum += value[i];
    }

    double ave = sum/count;
    double dev = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        dev += pow((value[i] - ave), 2);
    }

    dev = sqrt(dev / (count - 1));

    cout << "\nThe average is " << ave << "\n";
    cout << "The standard deviation is" << dev << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compiles and links fine here (`g++ main.cpp`). How are you compiling it?

Comment: Your code is fine. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I use the hammer button on eclipse to build it. It gives me this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are saying that your code is fine (I haven't tested it myself, though) so look around at your project directory, and see if there are any source files that shouldn't be there. If push comes to shove you can just copy/paste your code into a new project.

Comment: This error stop to pop up after I finished my dinner…I don't know why…but when I run the program. It stop working after I enter the value…weird.

Comment: Strange. Sometimes restarting the IDE fixes the problem.